# minio - s3 - bucket policy explanation

Tags: amazon-s3, policy, minio

In minio. when you set bucket policy to download with mc command like this:

```sh
mc policy set download server/bucket
```

The policy of bucket changes to:

```json
{
 "Statement": [
  {
   "Action": [
    "s3:GetBucketLocation",
    "s3:ListBucket"
   ],
   "Effect": "Allow",
   "Principal": {
    "AWS": [
     "*"
    ]
   },
   "Resource": [
    "arn:aws:s3:::public-bucket"
   ]
  },
  {
   "Action": [
    "s3:GetObject"
   ],
   "Effect": "Allow",
   "Principal": {
    "AWS": [
     "*"
    ]
   },
   "Resource": [
    "arn:aws:s3:::public-bucket/*"
   ]
  }
 ],
 "Version": "2012-10-17"
}
```

I understand that in second statement we give read access to anonymous users to download the files with url. What I don't understand is that why do we need to allow them to the actions **s3:GetBucketLocation, s3:ListBucket**.

Can anyone explain this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: These are basic permissions that enable to get access to top level of an object

Comment: @PrakashS Thanks, But without setting them I can download objects as normal!

Comment: Did you try as a normal user with the policy applied or with root user ?

Comment: @PrakashS None, without user but as a guest, from direct link for objects like 'localhost:9000/public-bucket/private.txt'

Comment: Please share the complete policy you have applied.

Answer (score 0):

`GetBucketLocation` is required to find the location of a bucket in some setups, and is required for compatibility with standard S3 tools like the `awscli` and `mc` tools.

`ListBuckets` is required to list the objects in a bucket. Without this permission you are still able to download objects, but you cannot list and discover them anonymously.

These are standard permissions that are safe to use and setup automatically by the `mc anonymous` command (previously called `mc policy`). It is generally not required to change them - though you can do so by directly calling the [`PutBucketPolicy` API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_PutBucketPolicy.html).